# Why does OpenInviter get authenticated login on my Local Machine but not on the webserver?

Tags: php, authentication, login-attempts

I have *no problem* testing on my local machine and then when i upload to webserver,
it is showing:

```
Login failed. Please check the email and password you have provided and try again later !
```

Tips:

- Post Installing all Ok.
- No any critical error **but only** warning with: `set_time_limit(0)`
- Testing for Gmail

Is this warning `set_time_limit(0)` the main cause OR why else?

Comment: the possibilities are too numerous to count.

Comment: I don't get "too numerous to count". What is that mean? If so, why it is working (get authenticated) on my local machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the possibilities could be that gmail has blocked your servers ip? is it a shared server? try some other account as well like live or yahoo or whatever just to see if this situation applies to all types of accounts or just gmail.

Comment: Now tested with "Yahoo!", but same output. ;(

Comment: This does not seem like the optimal answer :(